# How to display the page part after fixing the header and the footer

Tags: html, css, header, footer

I want to display my website by three parts: header, page and footer. Now I can fixed my header and my footer, but the header shields a part of page and the page dont put down my footer(some content of my page displays behind my footer )

My template code:

```
<div class="fixed-header">
  <...>
</div>

<div class="page">
  <...>
</div>

<div class="fixed-footer">
  <...>
</div>
```

My Css is :

```
.fixed-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%  !important;
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add padding on the top and bottom of the .page

```
.page {
  padding-top: x // height of header
  padding-bottom: x // height of footer
}
```

```css
.fixed-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  background: red;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 20px;
}

.fixed-footer {
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
}

.page {
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: pink;
  width: 100px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .fixed-header, .fixed-footer {
    height: 40px;
  }
  
.page {
  margin: 40px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-header">
  <...>
</div>

<div class="page">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi odio, est rerum quod nisi ipsam laboriosam quam eius doloremque exercitationem. Laboriosam aut consequatur atque natus beatae explicabo sunt. Quam, labore.
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi odio, est rerum quod nisi ipsam laboriosam quam eius doloremque exercitationem. Laboriosam aut consequatur atque natus beatae explicabo sunt. Quam, labore.
</div>

<div class="fixed-footer">
  <...>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but not very perfect. Because the height of header or footer changes with the size of screen. Any solution can adjust the padding for different size's screen.

Comment: Can you show some real code, with its structure because its hard to tell this way.

Comment: You can use media queries for different screen sizes.

Comment: Check out the snippet I just inserted.